# What is a proof of Euler's formula $e^{ix}=\cos(x)+i \sin(x)$ that doesn't use differentiation or De Moivre's theorem, if it exists at all?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

The Taylor series expansions of $e^x$, $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$ are the standard way to prove it, but does there exist an elementary way that doesn't use limits, calculus or De Moivre's theorem?

Comment: If you don't understand calculus or De Moivre's theorem, take the time to understand them as they build up your understanding of mathematics. It might be tempting to run before you can walk, but there really is no way to fully understand Euler's formula before you dive into the required mathematics.

Comment: What is your definition of $e^{ix}$, $\sin(x)$, $\cos(x)$ that does not use Taylor series or limits?

Comment: You need to clarify if $x$ is real or complex number. Please also specify what you mean by those symbols $e^{ix}, \cos x, \sin x$ for real or complex $x$. Usually textbooks do not provide their clear meaning when these symbols are introduced to students and are shameless in not being explicit about it. Assumption is that there is no need to know the meaning for beginners.

Answer (score 2):

The number $e$ is transcendental, so it seems impossible to obtain any non-trivial result about it that does not involve infinite processes (limits, derivatives, integrals...). If you want to define the exponential function for irrational arguments using the basic operations, it indeed seems difficult to avoid polynomials or rational functions, and these must be of infinite degree. Finally, to establish the theorem, you need some definition of the trigonometric functions that is not based on the complex exponential. For this you need to resort to well-axiomatized geometry and to establish the equivalence with statements in calculus. In the end, it boils down to computing the arc length along a circle, hence establish $\pi$, another transcendental number.

Answer (score 2):

If you take the trigonometric addition formulas for granted,

$$(\cos(n)+i\sin(n))(\cos(1)+i\sin(1))
\\=\cos(n)\cos(1)-\sin(n)\sin(1)+i(\cos(n)\sin(1)+\sin(n)\cos(1))
\\=\cos(n+1)+i\sin(n+1)$$

and by induction,

$$\cos(n)+i\sin(n)=(\cos(1)+i\sin(1))^n.$$

From this we have

$$\left(\cos\left(\frac nm\right)+i\sin\left(\frac nm\right)\right)^m=\cos(n)+i\sin(n)=(\cos(1)+i\sin(1))^n$$ and

$$\cos\left(\frac nm\right)+i\sin\left(\frac nm\right)=(\cos(1)+i\sin(1))^{n/m}$$ where we extract *some* to *some* $m^{\text{th}}$ root. In other words, with $q$ a rational number,

$$\cos(q)+i\sin(q)=(\cos(1)+i\sin(1))^q.$$

If we denote the complex number $\cos(1)+i\sin(1)$ as $e^i$, we have

$$\cos(q)+i\sin(q)=(e^i)^q.$$

---

This is by no means a proof (and if you wanted to generalize to the reals, you would need limits anyway), but it shows the connection between the addition formulas, which can be proven by geometry, and the powers of a complex.

---

Disclaimer: I didn't say that $(e^i)^q=e^{iq}$.

Answer (score 0):

I think we need to go in the opposite direction to get an understanding of why to **choose** (yes we actually get to choose) to expand the real exponential function to have the property that $$e^{i\phi} = \cos(\phi) + i\sin(\phi)$$

In the [analysis of one complex variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_analysis) there is introduced the concept of [analytic continuation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_continuation). As far as I remember this was the first good explanation of why to choose to expand the exponential function in this way.

If we do not put any particular restrictions on how well behaved a function shall be when we expand it's domain, then a lot of weird things can happen. The degrees of freedom of how to expand functions is basically limitless. There exist some really beautifully and disturbingly complicated functions in the wild.

But if we want to preserve well behavedness in the sense of [complex analyticity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_function) then we will need to choose the one which obeys De Moivre.

---

If we disregard differentiation altogether, then we suddenly have no particular reason to define the real valued exponential function to be smooth at all, and there's no reason as to why the number $e$ would be special. Remember what makes the number $e$ special is that $$\mathfrak D(e^{x}) = e^x$$

We could use base two instead and expand from integers to reals with a floor function or something. Without differentiability, why should our function be smooth?

Answer (score -1):

The relationship between $e^x$ and $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$

You know know the the $\text{exp()}$ function is a special one, and has many interesting properties among them is that expression $ e^{x} = \lim_{n \to \infty} (1+\frac{x}{n})^n $

If you expand this with binomial theorem, and put $n \rightarrow \infty$, you would get the series for $\text{exp()}$

$$ e^{x} = \lim_{n \to \infty} (1+\frac{x}{n})^n $$
$$ e^{x} = 1+x+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{6}+\frac{x^4}{24}+\frac{x^5}{120}+\frac{x^6}{720}+\frac{x^7}{5040} + \dots \dots $$
$$ e^{x}= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^k}{k!}$$
From this series, replace $x$ with $xi$, where $i = \sqrt{-1}$ and split the result into real and imaginary section
$$ e^{x} = 1+x+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{6}+\frac{x^4}{24}+\frac{x^5}{120}+\frac{x^6}{720}+\frac{x^7}{5040} + \dots \dots $$
$$ e^{xi} = 1+xi+\frac{(xi)^2}{2}+\frac{(xi)^3}{6}+\frac{(xi)^4}{24}+\frac{(xi)^5}{120}+\frac{(xi)^6}{720}+\frac{(xi)^7}{5040} + \dots \dots $$
$$ e^{xi} = \{ 1-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^4}{24}-\frac{x^6}{720}+ \dots \} + \{ x-\frac{x^3}{6}+\frac{x^5}{120}-\frac{x^7}{5040} + \dots \} \cdot i$$
$$\sin(x) = x-\frac{x^3}{6}+\frac{x^5}{120}-\frac{x^7}{5040} + \dots $$
$$\cos(x) = 1-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^4}{24}-\frac{x^6}{720}+ \dots $$

Therefore $e^{xi} = \cos(x)+i\sin(x)$